# What are the main market anomalies/inefficiencies detected in quantitative finance?

Tags: market-microstructure, factor-models, quantitative, anomalies, behavioral-finance

I wondered about the existence of a complete list of the anomalies detected in quantitative finance.

Generally, a **market anomaly** or inefficiency is a asset price and/or rate of return distortion on a financial market that actually contradicts the efficient-market hypothesis, as conceived by Fama's (1970) seminal paper.

Can you provide a list of them by posting the references of the relative books or papers?

Possibly, it would be greatly appreciated that you post the seminal paper reference, as, for instance, Basu (1977) in the case of the *size effect* or Thaler (1987) for the *January effect*.

I do not care about if they disappeared or not, but, instead, I'm interested to construct a full complete list of them.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

**NOTE**: I will update a list every time I find something new or a user post an answer with a new anomaly, in order to maintain the list updated.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "anomaly"?

Comment: Thanks for the criticism to the question, @vonjd! I edited the question inserting a general definition of market anomaly and edited the relative tag. Let me know whether the question need some clarification more.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make sense! Fama is in fact one of the most prominent advocates of the EMH! His factors like value or size are additional risk factors where investors get compensated for holding those risks! It would be same if you said beta is an anomaly because some people earn more than others when they hold more beta...

Comment: I agree with you, @vonjd! maybe I posted badly the question, but sorry I am not English mother tongue. Anyway, I know that Fama conceived the EMH theory, but that are a lot of cases that denied that theory and that, according to the literature, are examples of why the EMH is not true. Among those ones, there are the size effect, the January effect, the momentum/contrarian trading strategies,... I would like to get a complete list of those ones and here is my question.

Comment: @vonjd, I will be in chat if you're available to discuss about the question or to suggest some edit I could do. Please, ping me there!

Comment: @Quantopic vonjd presently has the top answer on a post discussing the difference between risk factors and anomalies. I'm not a particularly big fan of the answer, but it's consistent with academic finance. To me, it doesn't really matter what they're called. Size and value used to be considered anomalies by some, but now the profession calls them risk factors. Oh well.

Comment: Ok @John, thanks for the comment firstly! my intention was to collect those risk factors, anomalies or what else, just that. If you or vonjd have some advice to edit the question in order to question clearer or more interesting, it will be greatly appreciated. Alternatively, if you and others consider the question not useful to the site or simply not interesting, I will delete it. Anyway, the question is not about what can be considered an anomaly or risk factor or what else, but which they have been documented in the literature or by industry practitioners till now.

Comment: Here's a recent paper detailing over 80 anomalies: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2508322

Comment: You can find my answer John is referring to here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/15959/12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best overview I have seen so far is this paper which lists 214 (!) factors (or anomalies if you like) on over one hundred (!) pages:

Harvey, Campbell R. and Liu, Yan and Zhu, Caroline, …and the Cross-Section of Expected Returns (February 3, 2015). Available at SSRN: https://ssrn.com/abstract=2249314 or http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.2249314

Abstract:

> Hundreds of papers and hundreds of factors attempt to explain the
>   cross-section of expected returns. Given this extensive data mining,
>   it does not make any economic or statistical sense to use the usual
>   significance criteria for a newly discovered factor, e.g., a t-ratio
>   greater than 2.0. However, what hurdle should be used for current
>   research? Our paper introduces a multiple testing framework and
>   provides a time series of historical significance cutoffs from the
>   first empirical tests in 1967 to today. Our new method allows for
>   correlation among the tests as well as publication bias. We also
>   project forward 20 years assuming the rate of factor production
>   remains similar to the experience of the last few years. The
>   estimation of our model suggests that today a newly discovered factor
>   needs to clear a much higher hurdle, with a t-ratio greater than 3.0.
>   Echoing a recent disturbing conclusion in the medical literature, we
>   argue that most claimed research findings in financial economics are
>   likely false.

**EDIT**
The authors now provide a datasheet with an exhaustive overview of all factors: https://tinyurl.com/y23ozzkc

The following chart is taken from the paper and summarizes its key results:
[image]

**EDIT**
A new record! The following new paper lists and tests 452 (!) anomalies on more than 130 pages:

Hou, Kewei and Xue, Chen and Zhang, Lu, Replicating Anomalies (October 2018). Review of Financial Studies, forthcoming; Fisher College of Business Working Paper No. 2017-03-010; Charles A. Dice Center Working Paper No. 2017-10. Available at SSRN: https://ssrn.com/abstract=3275496

It indicates "that most published U.S. stock market anomalies are not replicable after reasonably demoting microcaps to a very minor role, and especially after raising the threshold for significance to account for data snooping."
Source and summary of the paper (behind a paywall):
https://www.cxoadvisory.com/29802/big-ideas/most-stock-anomalies-fake-news/

Abstract

> Most anomalies fail to hold up to currently acceptable standards for
>   empirical finance. With microcaps mitigated via NYSE breakpoints and
>   value-weighted returns, 65% of the 452 anomalies in our data library,
>   including 96% of the trading frictions category, cannot clear the
>   single test hurdle of the absolute t-value of 1.96. Imposing the
>   higher, multiple test hurdle of 2.78 at the 5% significance level
>   raises the failure rate to 82.1%. Even for the replicated anomalies,
>   their economic magnitudes are much smaller than originally reported.
>   In all, capital markets are more efficient than previously recognized.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @vonjd! I am going to read that and update the question to provide a full list of the market inefficiencies!

Answer (score 5):

You have started a huge job, an enormous number of anomalies have been reported. The web site quantpedia.com has a list, here for example is their writeup on [momentum effect in stocks](http://quantpedia.com/Screener/Details/14)

Comment: could you provide a link to the list?

Comment: +1 @noob2!! Really a good source! Thank you too for the answer!